# Quelles seraient des variantes de « avoir en tête », « traverser l’esprit »?

Tags: expressions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

J’avais aussi en tête d’écrire « ce propos tiendrait d’un pédophile » au lieu de « ce propos frise celui qu’aurait pu tenir un pédophile ».

L’idée m’a aussi traversé l’esprit d’écrire « ce propos tiendrait d’un pédophile » au lieu d’écrire « Ce propos frise celui qu’aurait pu tenir un pédophile ».

---

Ici il s’agit d’une formulation que j’ai omise volontairement car elle est d’une forte trivialité.

J’avais aussi l’idée d’écrire « ce propos tiendrait d’un pédophile » au lieu de « Ce propos frise celui qu’aurait pu tenir un pédophile ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il y a une différence entre les deux, et elle consiste en la durée de temps qui est sous-entendue en ce qui concerne le temps que l'idée reste dans l'esprit. « Avoir en tête » implique que l'idée est restée dans l'esprit assez longtemps, alors que « avoir trversé l'esprit » ne laisse supposerseulement que le moment est très court.

*Quelques synonymes, on doit pouvoir en trouver d'autres*

- **traverser l'esprit** : *passer par l'esprit*, *effleurer l'esprit* (nuance en plus, le « passage » est rapide, laisse une trace plus ou moins bien définie),
- **avoir en tête** : *envahir l'esprit* (avec une forte nuance en plus), *accaparer l'esprit* (avec une forte nuance en plus), *trotter dans la tête* (nuance : l'idée disparait mais revient plus ou moins régulièrement), *avoir dans l'idée*,

Answer (score 2):

> Quelles seraient des variantes de « avoir en tête », « traverser
> l’esprit »?

[*Penser*](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/penser_1), par exemple :

*Je pensais à écrire* [...] [concevoir]
*Je pensais écrire* [...] [avoir l'intention]

Answer (score 1):

On peut aussi dire "Je songeais à écrire..."  Qui indique une idée plus vague que "je pensais"